# Difference in meaning between "It is 500 miles" and "it is going to be 500 miles" in context

Tags: difference, present-simple, future-time

Would you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *it is 500 miles* and *it is going to be 500 miles* in the context below?

> The load is going from New York to Ohio. It **is** 500 miles in total/it *is going* to be 500 miles in total.

As a non-native English speaker, I can't see any difference. Is there any?2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is a very slight emphasis of time. You could use either quite properly and be understood correctly.

The "it is" form means that the journey is 500 miles long right now. That is, it is referring to the geographical arrangement of roads right now.

The "it is going to be" form means that the conditions when the journey happens will be 500 miles. You might need to choose this form if there was some complicating factor that made the journey different when the load is moved compared to right now. For example, if you had to detour for some temporary reason.

Most of the time nobody will notice the difference. They will understand them the same way.